# Changing look of pagination

Tags: pagination

I want to change number of pages displayed in pagination. Currently I have pagination like this:

<< < 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 > >>

I want to display it like this one:

<< < 1 2 ... 9 10 > >>

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what I'm looking for but it's resolved my problem.
https://gist.github.com/heesienooi/de010131dce82685bb0f

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the default pagination style with your own code. This is done by copying the link.php and links.php files from /layouts/joomla/pagination to your own template /templates/yourtemplate/html/layouts/joomla/pagination. The new files will be used to display pagination links, instead of the default ones. Now you can modify these to your likning. More about overriding joomla output is found here: https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides

Comment: It may also depend on your template. Yootheme/Warp7 templates for instance use a bit of a different technique to override the pagination.